# How to remove static variable value ,when will i close my activity

Tags: android

i want to clear variable value when will i close activity

Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you close your activity, the android OS will destroy any data associated with your application that isn't saved in a DB, and if you're worried about closing, then reopening the same activity, you can always assign default values to your variables upon creating them.. like

int x = 0;

sort of thing, this is always a good practice anyways! 
-M@

Comment: @i know but i am using static variable and static array in applications these variables are used for store images and retrieve the images from static array, so when did i close the application again images are stored in that,so when will i start new application that images are store in that variables